# Why do my wife and I have different heirs?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So I am playing the Game of Thrones MOD on CK2. My character married their son to the eventual Queen of the Iron Throne. My character died, and now my character is the King. Her heir is my now  oldest son, in line to inherit everything. However my heir is my oldest daughter (younger than the son), who is line to only gain the titles of my lands (The Fingers).

My question is why is my oldest son not my heir? How can I change it so that if I die, I become my son (the inheritor of the throne)?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your succession laws are. Only thing I can think of currently is elective succession and they really like your daughter.

Comment: Or the eldest son is the son of the Queen by previous marriage or a bastard.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to tinker with the succession/gender laws. Not sure whether this is possible or not in the Game of Thrones MOD as I've only ever played vanilla CK2.

It sounds like you want primogeniture succession and Agnatic-Cognatic gender laws. This should mean your eldest Son will inherit everything or in the absence of a son your eldest daughter will inherit everything.

Is your son's dynasty the same as your own or is it the same as your wife's?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are playing as Dornish (Idk what would a Dornish Lord be doing in Vale however. Maybe some inheritence or education issue).

In AGOT mod for CK2, Dornish succession laws emulate the Dornish laws in GRRM's universe.

Dornish succession is equivalent to Absolute-Cognatic, to put things in perspective of Vanilla CK2. That means, women inherit on same grounds as men.

So since your daughter is elder than your son, She stands higher in line of succession than your son.

In the meanwhile, Iron Throne must be following either Agnatic (Male only) or Agnatic-Cognatic (Males first) succession law. Which is why your consort gets your son as heir since he comes before your daughter being a male.

To make sure your heir is your son, you will have to change your succession law to either Agnatic or Agnatic-Cognatic, which will bring your eldest son to first in line of succession to Lordship of Fingers.

To change the law, You must be:

1. At Peace
2. Ruling in your own right with no regent
3. Holder of the target title for at least 10 years
4. Popular with no vassal having a negative opinion of you

Or to save yourself the trouble, you could just give your daughter a wee shove off the tallest tower in your castle.